# How to call the value corresponding to a coordinate in a 2D mesh (2D bin)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, grid

I have a temperature corresponding to a coordinate. Over the fixed area, I want to include a square grid (all the grids must have the same length). For this end I use `numpy.meshgrid` to generate the cells over my entire area. Now my question is how to sum up the temperature of each row whose coordinate are in kth cell? I am a bit confused as should I use the `numpy.histogram2d`? It is giving me the frequency of `X` and `Y`, does it mean I have to use multidimensional histogram?

Many thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


####generating input data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(2000, 6000, (1000000, 3)))
df.columns= ['X','Y', 'Temp']
x2 = np.linspace(df['X'].min(),df['X'].max(), 20)
y2 = np.linspace(df['Y'].min(),df['Y'].max(), 20 )
xx, yy =  np.meshgrid(x2, y2, indexing ='ij')
plt.scatter(xx, yy, color="red", marker="x");

#### Or should I use 
Hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(df['X'], df['Y'], bins = (x2,y2))
H = Hist.T
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Give me code to solve my problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @Prune Thanks for your comment! Tho i have done my fair share of research but will do more! Been on this code for a few days now.

Comment: @Prune I have my question edited and broke it down to a smaller question. Hopefully this is proper for the community to answer.

Comment: Well, if you have a temperature, you can look up that row in your dataframe and fetch the X and Y.  Given that, it's just a matter of truncating the X and Y values to your grid spacing.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your answer, but how to do that? If one writes a for loop and and if conditions then we will get the value of temperature if the condition is satisfied for that row (the condition is to being in one of the cells). And also should I use `numpy.histogram2d` in that case?

Comment: Your use case is not clear.  The question you asked is, "how do I find the X,Y for a given temperature?"  That's clearly a `for` loop solution.  A histogram can answer the question `how many temperatures were in each mesh grid bucket?".  Is that the question you meant to ask?  Because it's not what you asked.

Comment: @TimRoberts  My goal is to find the temperature at each grids no matter if it has 0 data point in that grid or 10 points in that grid. I think histogram is not helping because it exactly only returns the frequency of points in each bin. To solve this and call the temperature I might need to have the index of that row of data to find its temperature after it is allocated to a bin. Thanks for the feedback I have modified my question in the post.

Comment: OK, that's doable, although I'd use a loop to do it, rather than a dataframe.  If a grid has 10 points, do you want the mean?  If a grid has 0 points, what is the right answer?  I'll post something below, and you can see if it fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes your data set, and produces a 20x20 array that contains the average temperature of all the points within that grid.  If there are no temps in a grid, it will produce a NaN:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(2000, 6000, (100000, 3))

# We divide the coordinate space up into 20 bins.
binsize = (6000-2000) // 20

bins = np.zeros((20,20))
counts = np.zeros((20,20))

for row in data:
    binx = (row[0] - 2000) // binsize
    biny = (row[1] - 2000) // binsize
    bins[biny,binx] += row[2]
    counts[biny,binx] += 1

print( bins )
print( counts )
print( "Averages:" )
print( bins / counts )
```